# How to move from current PHP page to another PHP page if condition true?

Tags: php, html, web, web-applications, web-deployment

I am working on a web project where **I want to move from one PHP page to another Php page if condition true**...

In below login PHP page, I am getting  *username and password* using $_POST[]. if both username and password got matched in (**if statement**) of current PHP login page then, I want to jump to another PHP page(choice.php) specified in **header function** below after if.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <head>
 </head>
 <form method="post" action="login.php">

<div id="div1">
  <h1>welcome to bizdiary</h1>
  <div id="div2">

  <label >Username</label>
  <input id="name"  type="text" name="username" value="" 
       placeholder="username" />
  <label >Password</label><input type="text" name="password" value="" 
    placeholder="password"/>

  <input type='submit' name="login" value="login" >

     </form>

 <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];

     if($username=='root' && $password=='tiger'){
    header( "Location:http://localhost/bizdiary/choice.php" ); die;
      }
     }
   ?>
```

Comment: Remove unnecessary code before posting; and this is a must-read: [mcve]. And, please, at least indent your code properly.

Comment: Your script, rather messy, on 'submit' will try to redirect to a page called login.php - so this would normally be where you would process the data in the $_POST array. If however, as you seem to indicate, you want to redirect users to page ../choice.php, you should change $_POST['submit'], which doesn't exist, into $_POST['login'].

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

The HTML in top of the file.
Remove the action in your form.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];  
    // Put in here the conditional that the request need to accomplish to redirect.
    if($username=='root' && $password=='tiger'){            
        header("Location: http://{$host}/choice.php");
    }
}

?>
<html>
    <body>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">

            <div id="div1">
            <h1>welcome to bizdiary</h1>
            <div id="div2">

            <label >Username</label>
            <input id="name" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="username" />
            <label >Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" value="" placeholder="password"/>

            <input type='submit' name="login" value="login" >

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should mysql control. Example

```
if ($_POST){
        $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);

        if (empty($username) or empty($password)){
          echo 'Don't leave blank.';
        }else {
          $user = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = "'.$username.'" AND password = "'.$password.'"');

          if (mysql_num_rows($user)){

            header('Location: asd.php');
          }else {
            echo 'Didn't find user.';
          }
        }
      }
```